# How to clear the error message when we click reset button in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I created a web page displays users information and register a new user. If we try to enter existing user it is showing the error message. when I refresh the page the error is still exist. How to clear the error message when we refresh or when we click reset button.I am using spring Boot Here is my code.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>User Registration </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
    rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header" id="banner">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                <h1>Users</h1>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>UserId</th>
                            <th>USerName</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody border="0">
                        <tr  th:each="user :${users>
                            <td th:text="${user.userId}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${user.userName}" > </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Register USer</h1>

                    <form th:action="@{/registerUser}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Enter UserId</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userId" value=""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Enter UserName</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" value=""/>
                                </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">registerUSer</button>
                                    <button  type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div th:if="*{errorMessage != null}" class="alert alert-danger" th:text="*{errorMessage}">
                             </div>  
                        </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registrationForNewUSer(@RequestParam Long userId, @RequestParam String userName, Model model)
        throws Exception {
        //checking whether user already exist
    UserModel userInfo = userInfo.findOne(userId);
    if (userInfo != null) {
        String str = "user already exist" + userId;         
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", str);
        return usersList(model);
    } else {
        // 
        return "redirect:/registerUser/" + userId + "/" + userName;
    }
}



 @RequestMapping(value = "/usersList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String usersList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userInfo.findAll());
        return "usersview";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/registerUser/{userId}/{userName}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> authentication{
    // it does authenticationprocess and add user user in database and redirect to usersview.
    }
```

Comment: Please also add a controller method for adding new user.

Comment: You need to set errorMessage = null and add it to the model in the controller method which loads this page initially. It will remove errorMessage attribute from the model when the page is being refreshed.